# Trouble looping through array to pass values to database

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops

First of I need to mention I am new to coding so please keep that in mind. I am eager to learn and always try to look up things before asking questions and this is my first post on here.

What I am trying to do is pull a list of urls from my database and grab certain values to be added to my database. When I loop through the code it grabs everything correctly and gets all the info from every url but when it comes time to drop the info into the database it writes the first value of the array over and over again instead of writing the next value. Example: I have 3 urls, it pulls the info for all three

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
   (
   [title] => Data
   [promo] => Data
   [date] => Data
   [location] => Data
   )
  [1] => Array
   (
     [title] => Data
     [promo] => Data
     [date] => Data
     [location] => Data
   )
   [2] => Array
    (
     [title] => Data
     [promo] => Data
     [date] => Data
     [location] => Data
    )
 )
```

When I check my database the first data set is in there 3 times and the second and third are ignored. I have attached the code below in hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$select_db = mysql_connect('******','*******', '');
$connect_database = mysql_select_db('grab', $select_db);
$url=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM graber");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($url))
{
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html($row['urls']);

    // Find all article blocks
    foreach($html->find('div.event_detail') as $article)
    {
        $item['title'] =    $article->find('h1', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['promo'] =    $article->find('h2', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['date'] =     $article->find('div.authors_info span.date', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['location'] = $article->find('div.authors_info span.author', 0)->plaintext;
        $articles[] = $item;
    }

    $address=urlencode($articles[0]['location']);

    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');

    $output= json_decode($geocode);

    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    $title = $articles[0]['title'];
    $location = $articles[0]['location'];
    $promo = $articles[0]['promo'];
    $olddate = $articles[0]['date'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($olddate));
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo $lat.'<br />'.$long.'<br />'.$title.'<br />'.$location.'<br />'.$promo.'<br />'.$date.'<br /><br />';


            $dbc = mysqli_connect('********','*****','*******','*********')
            or die('Error I could not connect to DB');
            $query="INSERT INTO events(`id`,`parent`,`catid`,`contentid`,`type`,`title`,`location`,`summary`,`description`,`creator`,`startdate`,`enddate`,`permission`,`avatar`,`thumb`,`invitedcount`,`confirmedcount`,`declinedcount`,`maybecount`,`wallcount`,`ticket`,`allowinvite`,`created`,`hits`,`published`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`offset`,`allday`,`repeat`,`repeatend`)".
                    "VALUES('','0','1','0','profile','$title','$location','','$promo','24','$date','$date','0',NULL,NULL,'0','0','0','0','0','0','1','$today','0','1','$lat','$long','-6','1',NULL,'0000-00-00')";

            $results=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

            echo mysqli_error($dbc);
}
 mysqli_close($dbc);

 mysql_close($select_db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on php but it seems you are hardcoding the first dimension of the arrays to pick the first element.
For example 
`$address=urlencode($articles[0]['location']);`
should be something like:

```
$address=urlencode($articles[variable]['location']);
```

So everytime u need to insert into the database the values retrieved are different.

Comment: Mayank, I understand what you are saying but am not sure how to achieve it. With [variable] are you saying that it should be a $variable or ... I am thinking I moved to much of the code out of the foreach statement, creating code that is not necessary. I am trying to condense it and see what happens. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I figured it out. I simplified the code by removing unnecessary steps and it is working like a charm.

Comment: Yeah what I meant was instead of using a hardcoded dimension to access values in an array you need it to be an incremental variable (as you said $variable whose value increases by say 1, each time you run the loop). Glad you figured it out